# Dialogs still ask for user password (instead of root's) after adding rootpw to sudoers file

Tags: root, graphical-user-interface, kubuntu, administrative-privileges

To add an extra layer of security I'm using the `rootpw` option in the `sudoers` file and while it works perfectly fine from the shell, when a specific command invokes the GUI version of "elevation", only the user password will work in that case and not the root password. Do I need to change anything in PolicyKit config?

Kubuntu 18.10

I'd like the root password to be used everywhere, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waddayaknow! I found the answer myself: it's indeed to do with `policykit`. On my Kubuntu 18.10 I had to change the following file (`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf`) to have it say:

```
AdminIdentities=unix-user:root
```

instead of the default:

```
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

under the `[Configuration]` section.

Please note that other distro of Linux seem to use a different file for this setting as do other versions of the same distro as well (probably because of the different way that they handle `policykit`).

You're welcome!